# Confusion between stock-android and stock-ui tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

The [stock-android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-android) tag covers versions of the OS that *includes* manufacturer enhancements, but the [stock-ui](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-ui) tag *excludes* manufacturer enhancements (according to the description).

> **stock-android**
>   The version of Android originally on the device as supplied by the
>   manufacturer or phone network, including any customizations,
>   alternative interfaces and updates.
>
> **stock-ui**
>   A "stock user interface" refers to a device with the default Android user interface. It lacks both manufacturer/carrier
>   enhancements (e.g., Sense, BLUR) and customized ROMs from the mod
>   community.

From the description, wouldn't [vanilla-ui](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-ui) (which doesn't exist) be more appropriate? Or change the description?

Comment: I would agree with you on this, and there was a related discussion about stock vs vanilla here: [Let's revisit the "stock" vs. "vanilla" tagging, shall we?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/852) I'm somewhat inclined to say that `stock-ui` could simply be re-named. Questions about a *specific* stock UI (Sense, BLUR, TouchWiz, etc) should probably be using the more specific tags.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Yes, I think renaming the tag would be more appropriate. There appears to be only 5 questions that use the `stock-ui` tag and they all appear to use it in the correct 'vanilla' sense (although some of these also refer to `stock-android` when I think they really mean `vanilla-android`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and renamed [stock-ui](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-ui) to [vanilla-ui](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-ui). I've also updated the tag wiki and the handful of questions that were using the old tag to use the correct terminology. There did not appear to be any questions that were using [stock-ui](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-ui) to actually refer to a "stock" (manufacturer default) interface, so the tag is unused at this point.